# Rails 4 Devise Not Logging In

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise, controller, admin

I have a rails 4 app that uses devise for user authentication. Everything was working beautifully until I decided to add an "admin" parameter to the "Devise::User" model. I added it and created a custom User Controller to alloy my forms to update the fields. After I did this, I added more attributes. This is where my app started misbehaving. When I try to access an area with `before_action :authenticate_user!`, I get sent to the sign in page, implying that I'm not signed in. When I put in a users credentials and hit submit, I get sent to the `root_path` of the app with no notification of a successful (or failed) login instead of where I was going. When I try to go back to the restricted area (now that I'm "signed in") I get redirected to the sign in page again.

After reviewing all this, it seemed to me that devise is not actually logging in, so I added a log_out button to my home page to see if I could log out. When I click it, my logs say `Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected`. I'm not sure if that's normal or not (since I can't check now).

I'm at a complete loss as to where to go from here. I'm still a bit of a rails noob so it's possible the solution is staring me in the face.

Here's my `routes.rb`

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
      resources :musics, :composers, :music, :welcome, :charges, :tracks, :books

      root 'welcome#index'

      get 'admin' => 'welcome#admin'
      get 'admin/music/:id/tracks' => 'welcome#tracks', as: :admintracks

    end
```

And `RegistrationsController.rb`

```
    class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

      private

      def sign_up_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin, :fname, :lname, :company, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :phone)
      end

      def account_update_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :admin, :fname, :lname, :company, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :phone)
      end
    end
```

I appreciate all the help.

EDIT 1:
I confirmed that it is not logging in by placing a `<% if current_user %>Logged In<% end %>` line on my root_page. After logging in through the form, it still doesn't display. I then checked my logs to see what it gave for that log in and I don't spot anything fishy.

```
    Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2015-12-13 21:16:47 -0500
    Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HgStdwJajEbJMKyBgSGTD7Omqvdw9g6gmZwbXEmGd4VRFJqcLlrzjDYAdAWo7VdhpXm7sbNbuFTcR6neJTVr/g==", "user"=>{"email"=>"[*MyEmail*]@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
      User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "[*MyEmail*]@gmail.com"]]
       (0.1ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["last_sign_in_at", "2015-12-14 02:13:31.458050"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2015-12-14 02:16:47.893957"], ["sign_in_count", 27], ["updated_at", "2015-12-14 02:16:47.896163"], ["id", 1]]
       (1.1ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

Answer (score 0):

After related question jumping on here, I discovered an (unaccepted) answer to a related issue that solved my problem! In a previous attempt at something last night, I had messed with the `session store domain` and apparently just hadn't used anything relating to Devise since. Maybe this will help someone else!

Thanks, @amit_saxena